# Gmail out-of-office message script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using the following little script to create an out-of-office message for all emails arriving on Fridays and Saturdays. The scripts also marks them as read, as when they are unread it gets stuck in a loop and keeps sending back out-of-office messages.

The problem is that when I get back to my desk on Sunday I can't tell which new emails arrived, as they're already marked as 'read'. I do read many of my emails over the weekend so I can't just read back every email from the last weekend, it would take too long.

What I need is a way to leave these unread, and not have them stuck in a loop. Alternatively, I want to add the label 'out-of-office' to each email touched by this script, so I can review them on Sunday (assuming I'll remove the label if I answer the email before that).

```
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if ([5,6].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 0 && hour < 8) || (day == 4 && hour >= 19)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("Hello! Our offices are closed for the weekend. I will be monitoring my emails sporadically and will do my best to answer any urgent inquiries. If this is not urgent, I will reply to your email on Sunday morning. Thank you for your patience. Now go have a great weekend!");
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].markImportant();

      }
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This leaves the emails unread but keeps duplicate replys from being sent by filtering out unread emails with 'out-of-office' label.  This code has not been tested.

```
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  if(!isLabel('out-of-office')){GmailApp.createLabel('out-of-office');}//out-of-office label eliminates duplicate replies
  if ([5,6].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 0 && hour < 8) || (day == 4 && hour >= 19)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread() && threads[i].getLabels().indexOf('out-of-office')==-1)
      {
        threads[i].reply("Hello! Our offices are closed for the weekend. I will be monitoring my emails sporadically and will do my best to answer any urgent inquiries. If this is not urgent, I will reply to your email on Sunday morning. Thank you for your patience. Now go have a great weekend!");
        threads[i].markImportant();
        threads[i].addLabel('out-of-office');
      }
    }
  }}

function isLabel(labelname)
{
  return GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelname);
}
```